# How to group many generalization in one using ArgoUML in class diagram

Tags: uml, argouml

I have with ArgoUML. Anyone can advise me if group generalization exists in ArgoUML or not. If yes How and if No How I can do it in ArgoUML Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like group generalization. What you probably mean is multiple generalization arrows arriving at the same place. You simply do that by bending connectors in the right way (I'm using Enterprise Architect, but ArgoUML will have a similar tooling for sure).

Comment: Thank you very much for your interaction. I am using the same BUT the lines still separated. My objective is How to make those multiple generalization lines as a single line. Regards

Comment: I tagged your question with argouml, but there are not so many users as it seems (I used it last in 2000 or so).

Comment: Thank you very much. If you can help me. what is the best professional UML  tool for large systems and IT ACCEPT MY ALREADY CREATED ARO FILES?

Comment: Well, "the best" does not exist. I use Enterprise Architect which has a good (the best?) price performance ratio, but a weird UI. Most other tools are much more expensive.